# How to let my computer know I want to use python 3 now?

Tags: python, django, pythonpath

I have a mac and python 2.something installed. I recently installed python3 and pip3. Then I tried running the following commands:

```
pip3 install django==2.2

django-admin startproject myProject

cd myProject
```

everything worked, but when I run

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

it complains

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

is my computer still thinking in the old version? I am not familiar with "environment variables" do I need to modify it? (I am asking cause I also read that it can be unsafe to modify that stuff)

Also, when I run

```
python --version
```

it gives me 2.7

however I can still run .py files using "python3" command

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? I use something like 
"mkvirtualenv --python=`which python3` <name>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using first `python3 -m pip install django`

and then run the command `python3 manage.py runserver`

looks like you are installing django on Python 2

Comment: thanks. This worked although I would like to understand what just happened. So do I have to run that "pyton3 -m pip install django" command every time I want to create a new django project?

Comment: No, just once, it will only be necessary if you are using virtual-env.


No, just once, it will only be necessary if you are using virtual-env

When you do not specify the python version, it automatically uses the default version of your system which is 2.7.

To create new projects use django-admin startproject "project name"

Comment: any reason why you did not suggest me to type django==2.2 for the version in that command? you just suggested me "django".

Comment: No reason, you can continue to specify the version if you normally need it, the only difference is that it will look for the latest version if not specified.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a virtual environment. I would suggest not trying to substitute `python` with `python3` just yet, since you might still have programs that depend on Python 2.

Instead, you can try to install django with the command:

```
python3 -m pip install django==2.2
```